# Синхронизация в Java

Tags: java, synchronized

```
@ThreadSafe
public class MyLock {
    @GuardedBy("lock")
    volatile Boolean lock = false;

    public MyLock() {
    }

    public void lock() throws InterruptedException {
        if (lock) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                lock.wait();
            }
        } else {
            lock = true;
        }
    }

    public void unlock() {
        lock = false;
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notify();
        }
    }
} `
```

Смысл такой: заходят три потока с очередностью в три секунды, первый поток как надо проходит остальные два ждут, но когда доходит до просыпания потоки не просыпаются в `debug` так и остаются в состоянии `waiting`.

Исправить знаю как, нашел один способ либо весь метод сделать `synchronized` или все тело внутри метода в `synchronized block` завести, но по сути этот вариант тоже должен рабочий ведь переменная `volatile`, очень жду помощи что именно происходит в таком варианте событий.

Comment: Смысл такой что, заходят три потока с очередностью в три секунды, первый поток как надо проходит остальные два ждут, но когда доходит до просыпания потоки не просыпаются в debug так и остаются в состоянии waiting, исправить знаю как
нашел один способ либо весь метод сделать `synchronized`или все тело внутри метода в `synchronized block` завести,
но по сути этот вариант тоже должен рабочий ведь переменная `volatile`, очень жду помощи что именно происходит в таком варианте событий)

Comment: По моему, когда второй поток заходит в синхронизированный блок метода lock, третий поток ждёт, пока он будет завершен. Когда первый поток заходит в метод unlock, он тоже ждёт, пока второй поток выйдет из синхронизированного блока

Comment: Синхронизация производится на мониторе конкретного объекта. Когда вы меняете true на false, сменяется сам объект, и бестолку ждать, что notify будет вызван на старом мониторе.

Comment: Неуловил немного, почему третий поток ждет? когда второй поток ушел в wait он отдал монитор, и третий тоже потом зашел и отдал, все это во время пока первый поток 'спит' или что то вычисляет, затем когда первый поток закончил работу он попадает на метод unlock() и по сути должен пробудить спавший который шел за ним и так все далее.

Comment: @fox.ontour нет, он не отдает монитор

Comment: wait(): освобождает монитор и переводит вызывающий поток в состояние ожидания до тех пор, пока другой поток не вызовет метод notify() нашел на каком то сайте, и если бы не отдавал моя реализация 
с threadPool тоже бы не работала)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы делаете `lock = false;` у вас меняется объект в `lock`, и вы вызываете `notifyAll()` не на том объекте, на котором делаете `wait()`.

Сделайте мьютекс отдельно, флаг отдельно и меняйте флаг после захвата мьютекса. Ожидание так же нужно делать в цикле, т.к. проснувшийся поток может снова войти в критическую секцию уже после того, как флаг снова изменится.

```
@ThreadSafe
public class MyLock {
    final Object mutex = new Object();

    @GuardedBy("mutex")
    boolean locked = false;

    public MyLock() {
    }

    public void lock() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            while (locked) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                mutex.wait();
            }

            locked = true;
        }
    }

    public void unlock() {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            locked = false;
            mutex.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так теперь можно уточню кое-что
получается что классы обертки ни как не подходят в виде мьютекса?

Comment: Boolean immutable чтоль?

Comment: все сори за глупый вопрос понял)

Comment: обычный `Object` ничем не хуже (ну если вы не безумны и не используете объекты кэша `Integer`). `Boolean` иммутабелен, но это здесь не важно, т.к. присваивание любой переменной ссылочного типа устанавливает в нее ссылку на новый объект. Вы, допустим, можете объявить массив `boolean[] lock = {false}`, и делать присвоение его элементу `synchronized( lock ) { lock[0] = true; }`, это будет работать.

Comment: Просто думал что класс обертка это что то типа:
class Boolean {
boolean value;
public Boolean (boolean b) {
value = b;
}
}

Comment: @fox.ontour [так и есть](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Boolean.java#Boolean), но когда вы делаете `Boolean b = true; b = false;`, происходит не `b.value = false`, а `b = Boolean.valueOf( false )`, т.е. переменная `b` будет указывать на другой объект.